# spark-ts TimeSeriesRDD - how to create DateTimeIndex with hourly frequency?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, time-series, cloudera

I am following the [cloudera blog on using spark-ts for time series analysis in scala](https://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2015/12/spark-ts-a-new-library-for-analyzing-time-series-data-with-apache-spark/). I would like to create a DateTimeIndex with hourly frequency. The example in the blog shows how to create a DateTimeIndex with business day frequency as follows:

```
val dtIndex = DateTimeIndex.uniform(
  new DateTime("2015-08-03"), new DateTime("2015-09-22"), new BusinessDayFrequency(1))
```

I was hoping to find the solution in the [github repository of DateTimeIndex.scala from author Sandy Ryza](https://github.com/sryza/spark-timeseries/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/cloudera/sparkts/DateTimeIndex.scala), but could not figure it out so far.

How would I need to modify the above example to generate an index with hourly frequency?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an `HourFrequency` class:

```
val dtIndex = DateTimeIndex.uniform(
  new DateTime("2015-08-03"), new DateTime("2015-09-22"), new HourFrequency(1))
```

(https://github.com/sryza/spark-timeseries/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/cloudera/sparkts/Frequency.scala#L125-L129)